# Using useEffect to fetch data with redux thunk and end up with infinity loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, use-effect

I am using redux thunk with useEffect to fetch data from API. However I end up with infinity loop of fetching data from API. I put empty array as second parameter in useEffect but it still fetch data for infinite times. However can I solve the issue. Here is my code:

Here is AcademicYearList.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import cx from 'classnames';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import Academic from '@material-ui/icons/CalendarToday';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import Delete from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import GridContainer from 'components/theme/Grid/GridContainer';
import GridItem from 'components/theme/Grid/GridItem';
import Card from 'components/theme/Card/Card';
import CardBody from 'components/theme/Card/CardBody';
import CardIcon from 'components/theme/Card/CardIcon';
import CardHeader from 'components/theme/Card/CardHeader';
import ThemeButton from 'components/theme/CustomButtons/Button';
import Table from 'components/common/Table/Table';
import LoadablePaper from 'components/common/Paper/LoadablePaper';
import LoadablePaperContent from 'components/common/Paper/LoadablePaperContent';

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getTranslate } from 'react-localize-redux';
import * as ROUTES from 'variables/routeNames';
import { getAcademicYears } from 'redux/actions/academicYear';
import settings from 'settings';

import styles from 'assets/sts/jss/views/academicYear/academicYearStyle';
import * as moment from 'moment';

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

const AcademicYear = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const localize = useSelector((state) => state.localize);
  const isLoading = useSelector(state => state.academicYear.isLoadingGet);
  const academicYears = useSelector(state => state.academicYear.academicYears);
  const translate = getTranslate(localize);

  const fetchData = useCallback(
      () => dispatch(getAcademicYears()),
      [dispatch]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (academicYears.length === 0 && !isLoading) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <LoadablePaper
      rendered
      loading={isLoading}
    >
      <LoadablePaperContent>
        <GridContainer>
          <GridItem xs={12}>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader color="gold" icon>
                <CardIcon color="gold">
                  <Academic />
                </CardIcon>
                <h4 className={classes.cardIconTitle}>{translate('academicYear.title')}</h4>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <Table
                  size='small'
                  tableHead={[
                    { id: 'start_year', isNeedSort: false, label: translate('academicYear.year') },
                    { id: 'start_date', isNeedSort: false, label: translate('academicYear.start') },
                    { id: 'end_date', isNeedSort: false, label: translate('academicYear.finish') },
                    { id: 'short_vacation', isNeedSort: false, label: translate('academicYear.vacation.short') },
                    { id: 'long_vacation', isNeedSort: false, label: translate('academicYear.vacation.long') },
                    { id: 'action', isNeedSort: false, label: '' }
                  ]}
                  tableData={
                    academicYears.map(academic => {
                      const start_date = moment(academic.start_date, settings.dateFormat);
                      const end_date = moment(academic.end_date, settings.dateFormat);
                      const studyYear = `${start_date.year()}-${end_date.year()}`;
                      const editButton = (
                          <Tooltip
                              title={translate('common.button.edit')}
                              key={translate('common.button.edit')}
                          >
                            <IconButton
                                color='primary'
                                aria-label='edit'
                                className={classes.tableIconButton}
                                component={Link}
                                to={`${ROUTES.ACADEMIC_YEAR_EDIT_ROOT}/${academic.id}`}
                            >
                              <Edit className={classes.icon} />
                            </IconButton>
                          </Tooltip>
                      );
                      const deleteButton = (
                          <Tooltip
                              title={translate('common.button.delete')}
                              key={translate('common.button.delete')}
                          >
                            <IconButton
                                color='secondary'
                                aria-label='delete'
                                className={classes.tableIconButton}
                                onClick={() => {console.log('delete')}}
                            >
                              <Delete className={classes.icon} />
                            </IconButton>
                          </Tooltip>
                      );
                      return [
                        studyYear,
                        academic.start_date,
                        academic.end_date,
                        academic.short_vacation ? `${academic.short_vacation.start_date}-${academic.short_vacation.end_date}` : '',
                        academic.long_vacation ? `${academic.long_vacation.start_date}-${academic.long_vacation.end_date}` : '',
                        [editButton, deleteButton]
                      ];
                    })}
                  customCellClasses={['center', 'center', 'center']}
                  customClassesForCells={[3, 4, 5]}
                  customHeadCellClasses={['center', 'center', 'center']}
                  customHeadClassesForCells={[3, 4, 5]}
                  count={20}
                  limit={10}
                  page={0}
                />
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
            <Link to={ROUTES.ACADEMIC_YEAR_NEW}>
              <ThemeButton
                color="primary"
                className={classes.allButton}
              >
                {translate('common.button.new')}
              </ThemeButton>
            </Link>
          </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>
      </LoadablePaperContent>
    </LoadablePaper>
  );
};

export default AcademicYear;
```

Here is my action:

```
export const getAcademicYears = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getAcademicRequested());
    axios.get('/get-academic-years')
      .then(
        res => {
          dispatch(getAcademicSuccess(res.data.data));
        }
      )
      .catch(e => {
        dispatch(getAcademicFail(e));
        dispatch(showErrorNotification(e.message));
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: most probably the parent component is re-rendering and hence the child too. The empty array in useEffect ensures that the component doesn't re-renders on its own state change but if the parent component's state is changing this would happen.

Comment: Please share as much of the `AcademicYearList` component as possible, and if also possible, the component rendering it?

Comment: @DrewReese I have add my whole AcademicYearList

Comment: As Mohit suggested it looks like `AcademicYear` is being remounted, and hence running the useEffect again. Can you paste the parent components code?

Comment: Thank you you guy @MattWay and Mohit Singh. I have figured out the issue. Now it is working fine.